# How to you prove $|a|=|-a|$ is true

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing, proof-explanation, absolute-value

Let $a \in R$ prove that:

$|a|=|-a|$

I am new to proofs so this is my attempt:

Case 1: $|a|=|-a|$

$$(a)=-(-a)$$

$$a=a$$

Case 2: $|-a|=|-a|$

$$-(-a)=-(-a)$$

$$a=a$$

Case 3: $|a|=|a|$

$$a=a$$

Is this the correct way to approach a proof like this?

Comment: I don't understand the cases you are distinguishing.

Comment: Make your cases $a>0, a<0, a=0$   An alternative would be to say $|a| = \sqrt {a^2} = \sqrt {(-a)^2} = |-a|$

Comment: Hint:  $|a|$ is the greater of $a,-a$.

Comment: It's going to depend on how you define $|a|$. There are several ways to do it; which one are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Because the distances from $a$ and from $-a$ to the zero  are equal.

Answer (score 0):

The definition of absolute value of a real number $a$ is $|a|=\sqrt{x^2}$. Since $a^2=(-a)^2$ and square roots only take positive values $|a|=|-a|$

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to do a case by case proof, you only need to consider two cases:

Case 1: 
$a \ge 0 \\ \Rightarrow |a|=a, |-a|=a \\ \Rightarrow |a|=|-a|$

Case 2: 
$a < 0 \\ \Rightarrow |a|=-a, |-a|=-a \\ \Rightarrow |a|=|-a|$